# spark: How to merge shuffled rdd efficiently?

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I have 5 shuffled key-value rdds, one big one(1,000,000 records), and 4 relative small ones(100,000 records).All rdds were shullfed with the same number of partitions, I have two strategies to merge the 5 one,

1. Merge the 5 rdds together
2. merge the 4 small rdds together and then join the bigone

I think the strategy 2 would be more efficiently, as it **would not re-shuffle the big one**. But the experiment result shows the **strategy 1** more efficient. The code and output are following:

**Code**

```
import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.{SparkContext, SparkConf}


object MergeStrategy extends App {

    Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR)
    Logger.getLogger("akka").setLevel(Level.ERROR)

    val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[4]").setAppName("test")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)

    val bigRddSize = 1e6.toInt
    val smallRddSize = 1e5.toInt
    println(bigRddSize)

    val bigRdd = sc.parallelize((0 until bigRddSize)
        .map(x => (scala.util.Random.nextInt, 0))).repartition(100).cache
    bigRdd.take(10).foreach(println)

    val smallRddList = (0 until 4).map(i => {
        val rst = sc.parallelize((0 until smallRddSize)
            .map(x => (scala.util.Random.nextInt, 0))).repartition(100).cache
        println(rst.count)
        rst
    }).toArray

    // strategy 1
    {
        val begin = System.currentTimeMillis

        val s1Rst = sc.union(Array(bigRdd) ++ smallRddList).distinct(100)
        println(s1Rst.count)

        val end = System.currentTimeMillis
        val timeCost = (end - begin) / 1000d
        println("S1 time count: %.1f s".format(timeCost))
    }

    // strategy 2
    {
        val begin = System.currentTimeMillis

        val smallMerged = sc.union(smallRddList).distinct(100).cache
        println(smallMerged.count)

        val s2Rst = bigRdd.fullOuterJoin(smallMerged).flatMap({ case (key, (left, right)) => {
            if (left.isDefined && right.isDefined) Array((key, left.get), (key, right.get)).distinct
            else if (left.isDefined) Array((key, left.get))
            else if (right.isDefined) Array((key, right.get))
            else throw new Exception("Cannot happen")
        }
        })
        println(s2Rst.count)

        val end = System.currentTimeMillis
        val timeCost = (end - begin) / 1000d
        println("S2 time count: %.1f s".format(timeCost))
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
1000000
(688282474,0)
(-255073127,0)
(872746474,0)
(-792516900,0)
(417252803,0)
(-1514224305,0)
(1586932811,0)
(1400718248,0)
(939155130,0)
(1475156418,0)
100000
100000
100000
100000
1399777
S1 time count: 39.7 s
399984
1399894
S2 time count: 49.8 s
```

My understanding for shuffled rdd was wrong? Can anybody give some advices?
Thanks!

Comment: You are not doing any join in strategy 1 (only union) while you are doing a join in strategy 2. Why is that? Remember union does not need to shuffle data -- it can just stich up the RDDs that are present on each executor. More specifically, Union only creates a narrow dependency while join creates a shuffle dependency. So it appears that strategy 1 and 2 are apples and oranges.

Comment: @SachinTyagi My target is to distinct the 5 rdds, strategy 1 and 2 both distinct at last. distinct will shuffle the data. As big rdd have already shuffled, so strategy 2 would not shuffle the big one, and should be more efficient, but the experiment shows the opposite.

Comment: Not quite sure I understand, but whenever you do join, you will introduce a shuffle dependency and thus you end up (re-)shuffling the data. No matter if  your rdd was shuffled earlier or not. And that is consistent with what you're seeing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a method to merge rdd more efficiently, see the following 2 merging strategies:

```
import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.{HashPartitioner, SparkContext, SparkConf}
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer

object MergeStrategy extends App {

    Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR)
    Logger.getLogger("akka").setLevel(Level.ERROR)

    val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[4]").setAppName("test")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)

    val rddCount = 20
    val mergeCount = 5
    val dataSize = 20000
    val parts = 50

    // generate data
    scala.util.Random.setSeed(943343)
    val testData = for (i <- 0 until rddCount)
        yield sc.parallelize(scala.util.Random.shuffle((0 until dataSize).toList).map(x => (x, 0)))
            .partitionBy(new HashPartitioner(parts))
            .cache
    testData.foreach(x => println(x.count))

    // strategy 1: merge directly
    {
        val buff = ArrayBuffer[RDD[(Int, Int)]]()
        val begin = System.currentTimeMillis
        for (i <- 0 until rddCount) {
            buff += testData(i)
            if ((buff.size >= mergeCount || i == rddCount - 1) && buff.size > 1) {
                val merged = sc.union(buff).distinct
                    .partitionBy(new HashPartitioner(parts)).cache
                println(merged.count)

                buff.foreach(_.unpersist(false))
                buff.clear
                buff += merged
            }
        }
        val end = System.currentTimeMillis
        val timeCost = (end - begin) / 1000d
        println("Strategy 1 Time Cost: %.1f".format(timeCost))
        assert(buff.size == 1)

        println("Strategy 1 Complete, with merged Count %s".format(buff(0).count))
    }


    // strategy 2: merge directly without repartition
    {
        val buff = ArrayBuffer[RDD[(Int, Int)]]()
        val begin = System.currentTimeMillis
        for (i <- 0 until rddCount) {
            buff += testData(i)
            if ((buff.size >= mergeCount || i == rddCount - 1) && buff.size > 1) {
                val merged = sc.union(buff).distinct(parts).cache
                println(merged.count)

                buff.foreach(_.unpersist(false))
                buff.clear
                buff += merged
            }
        }
        val end = System.currentTimeMillis
        val timeCost = (end - begin) / 1000d
        println("Strategy 2 Time Cost: %.1f".format(timeCost))
        assert(buff.size == 1)

        println("Strategy 2 Complete, with merged Count %s".format(buff(0).count))
    }

}
```

The result shows that strategy 1 (time cost 20.8 seconds) is more efficient than strategy 2 (time cost 34.3 seconds). my pc is  window 8, CPU 4 cores 2.0GHz, 8GB memory.

The only difference is that strategy partitioned by HashPartitioner, but strategy 2 not. As a result, the strategy 1 produce ShuffledRDD, but strategy 1 MapPartitionsRDD.  I think **RDD.distinct** function processes ShuflledRDD more efficiently than MapPartitionsRDD.